# Why is an information in my printf() function incorrect in MQL4?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

My print formatting is giving me random answers, despite my coding being correct. I'm trying to display the candle bar lengths of the previous two candle bars prior to a trade entry. Here is the coding I've used.

`PCL1` & `PCL2` are the relevant field entries. They are divided by `_Point` to give an integer formatting.

`PCL2` = Previous Candle Stick length, Shift 2

`PCL1` = Previous Candle Stick length, Shift 1

In this example I have focused on the Shift2 Candlestick

```
Short_Bull_2_Close   =  iClose( Symbol(), 0, 2 );
Short_Bull_2_Open    =  iOpen(  Symbol(), 0, 2 );
CandleBody_2         =  ( Short_Bull_2_Close - Short_Bull_2_Open );
                     // Gives the Candlebody length in pips.
```

And this is my **`printf()`** coding:

```
printf( "PCL1 [%d] PCL2 [%d]", CandleBody_1 / Point,
                               CandleBody_2 / Point
        ); // ___________________________________________________________  SELL//
```

However, all I get is as pictured & highlighted..[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1) MQL4 is a strong typed language  <sup>( declaration precedes any use of a variable )</sup>
 + MQL4 has a historical feature of a number "normalisation"

> An assumption `(cit.)` "They are divided by `_Point` to give an integer" **does not hold.**

Once any number has been declared **`double`** in a source code as:

```
double upFractal = 0.0,
       dnFractal = 0.0;
```

the MQL4-compiler handles these numbers forever in an IEEE-754 floating point number representation and calls particular sub-version of operations on any arithmetics operation such number is entring into. The reason is simple, **`double`** has different handling than ( *New*-`MQL4.56789` ) **`float`**, the more than **`int`** et al. Some numbers, represented in IEEE-754, are inexact by-definition, some could remain exact ( if they happen to be some direct power-of-2 and still in it's "virgin"-state ( have not yet been spoiled by any arithmetic operation, that would introduce an un-avoidable im-precision into their binary-representatio ) ).

**Why im-precision?

Why un-avoidable?**
For non-virgin numbers, the binary-representation may yield into an infinitely-long description of the value. On the contrary, the storage of any value in MQL4 is restricted to **`{ 1 | 4 | 8 }`**-bytes of memory-space and thus the infinite-representation is **un-avoidably** cut at some distance, introducing a principal **im-precision** , expressed by:

**`DBL_EPSILON`** ~ `2.2204460492503131e-016`
**`FLT_EPSILON`** ~ `1.192092896e-07`
beyond which any two numbers, represented in IEEE-754 binary-format, look to the compiled code as "equal", even if they are not principally equal, just due to the IEEE-754 format inherent im-precision.

For indeed historical reasons, `double` typed values ought have been always **`NormalizeDouble()`** converted, if one wants to send these to the MetaTrader Server-side processing and/or compare values on a fair ground.

### 2) MQL4 operations with `{double | int }`- typed variables

If one had declared a variable to be `double`, it remains `double` forever.
If one had declared a variable to be `int`, even an `int/3` will remain `int`, ignoring the fractional products of division operation ( which sometimes causes headaches to not so carefull MQL4 coders ).

The same applied to an initial assumption above yields to a surprise, that `double/double -> double` even in cases, the division could be satisfactorily considered  <sub>( almost )</sub>  integer. So never assume a type conversion to happen just by the values of the operands.

For that purpose, there are two sorts of syntax-supports:

- an explicit **conversion** function **`int( ... )`** or **`double( ... )`**
- an inline **typecast** directive **`( (int) CandleBody_1 / _Point )`**

---

### Epilogue:  <sup>( ... a must read for Custom Indicator designers, where CPU-performance kills )</sup>

> As said above, calling **`(int) NormalizeDouble(...)`** is a double-nonsense ( well beyond a belt + suspenders paradigm ), first, as a historically built-in function `NormalizeDouble` still returns **`double`**, thus providing zero-benefit from spending CPU to crunch the numbers once it still yields a `double`, next as the division of the number a `double` value of `_Point` is very expensive and inefficient, compared to the fact, the `_Point` is related to `int` value of `Digits` by a formula of `1 / 10^Digits` -- so the fastest and cleanest way to do the conversion, without spending avoidable CPU-cycles, is **MULTIPLICATION** ... 
> yes,
> from a computer-side of fast & efficient processing, **the best is**
> `int( MAKE_aPriceDOMAIN_VALUE_an_INT_NUM_OF_POINTs * CandleBody_1 )`,
> re-using a constant
> `int  MAKE_aPriceDOMAIN_VALUE_an_INT_NUM_OF_POINTs = MathPow( 10, Digits );`

Answer (score 0):

you must convert to integer, you may think that you obtain a real number equivalent to integer but converter doesn't think so.

```
printf("%d",  (int)NormalizeDouble(CandleBody_2/Point,0) );
```